# How do I change the style of a path in the Google Maps api in Codename one

Tags: java, codenameone

I am making an app for school and I am using the Google Maps Library in Codename one. I create a path between various points but the path is thin and black and very hard to see.

I've looked at all the codename one documentation on the subject and couldn't find any way to change the thickness or color.

Is there a way to change the style that I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We don't support customizing that at this time although you could probably draw your path on your own using a painter. A better approach might be [filing an RFE](http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/) to add a feature for coloring/sizing the path.